# tyConPackage changed from ghc-7.8 to ghc-7.10?

Tags: haskell, ghc

This ghci session

```
import Data.Map
import Data.Typeable
tyConPackage $  typeRepTyCon $  typeOf $ fromList [(1,2)]
```

gives

```
in ghc-7.8.4: "containers-0.5.5.1"
in ghc-7.10.1: "conta_47ajk3tbda43DFWyeF3oHQ"
```

the new behaviour breaks my application, as I use this string
to programmatically construct documentation URLs (pointing to html built by standalone-haddock)

Is there a way to get back the old behaviour? Some work-around?

--

I did some more research and found (ghc/compiler/basicTypes/Module.lhs):

7.8.4 (compiler/typecheck/TcGenDeriv builds the instance and) uses

```
-- | Essentially just a string identifying a package, including the version: e.g. parsec-1.0
newtype PackageId = PId FastString deriving( Eq, Typeable )
```

7.10.1 (compiler/deSugar/DsBinds constructs the evidence(?) and) uses

```
-- | A string which uniquely identifies a package.  For wired-in packages,
-- it is just the package name, but for user compiled packages, it is a hash.
newtype PackageKey = PId FastString deriving( Eq, Typeable )
```

Well, "uniquely identify" is nice, but ...

--

On the other hand, ghci somehow knows the (ungarbled) package name:

```
import Data.Map ; :i Map
data Map k a = containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base.Bin ...
```

but that's at compile time - I still hope this info is available at runtime someplace.

Comment: I get the same output that you do, so it's at least reproducible.  I know there were changes made to how `Typeable` works in 7.10 (IIRC all types now implement `Typeable` automatically), but I don't know how this plays into it.  I don't think it's a change to `tyConPackage` since that's actually a record field, and `typeRepTyCon` is basically the same thing, just a field accessor.  That leaves `typeOf` as the culprit, but this calls a built-in `typeRep#` on a `Proxy# (Map Int Int)`, which means the culprit is further down.

Comment: You could use `tyConModule`, but that only gets `Data.Map.Base`, which probably isn't enough to really build documentation on top of haddock.  The typeable stuff in the latest version of `containers` for the `Map` type looks like it's relying on C to build the actual `Typeable` instance.  Hopefully someone can come along who knows more than I do and can shed some light on what's actually going on, though.

Comment: the garbled name is indeed the file name ("cabal install" prints it after "Installing library in", and indeed, files are there) There must be a way to get to the package name? ("ghc-pkg list" can do this).

Comment: @bheklilr this "containers" is only an example - I actually need this for my own packages (several of them, documentation merged together by standalone-haddock), and I always use "deriving Typeable", so it must be something inside ghc that changed. I'll add more info to the question.